# Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update

Tags: composer-php, laravel-8, database-connection

I don't understand why i coudn't run the composer install or composer update. it gives me an error

```
almando@think:~/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce$ composer install
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - laracon21/colorcodeconverter is locked to version 1.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laracon21/colorcodeconverter 1.2 requires php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - laracon21/combinations is locked to version 1.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laracon21/combinations 1.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - laracon21/timezones is locked to version 1.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laracon21/timezones 1.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - lcobucci/jwt is locked to version 3.4.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - lcobucci/jwt 3.4.6 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - mehedi-iitdu/core-component-repository is locked to version v1.8 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - mehedi-iitdu/core-component-repository v1.8 requires php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - mpdf/mpdf is locked to version v8.1.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - mpdf/mpdf v8.1.3 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
  Problem 7
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet is locked to version 1.25.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.25.2 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
  Problem 8
    - simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode is locked to version 4.2.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode 4.2.0 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
  Problem 9
    - fzaninotto/faker is locked to version v1.9.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - fzaninotto/faker v1.9.2 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 10
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.25.2 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.44 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.25.2].
    - maatwebsite/excel is locked to version 3.1.44 and an update of this package was not requested.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
almando@think:~/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laracon21/colorcodeconverter 1.2 -> satisfiable by laracon21/colorcodeconverter[1.2].
    - laracon21/colorcodeconverter 1.2 requires php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires laracon21/combinations 1.2 -> satisfiable by laracon21/combinations[1.2].
    - laracon21/combinations 1.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Root composer.json requires laracon21/timezones 1.2 -> satisfiable by laracon21/timezones[1.2].
    - laracon21/timezones 1.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - Root composer.json requires lcobucci/jwt ^3.4.5 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[3.4.5, 3.4.6, 3.4.x-dev].
    - lcobucci/jwt[3.4.5, ..., 3.4.x-dev] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - Root composer.json requires mehedi-iitdu/core-component-repository 1.8 -> satisfiable by mehedi-iitdu/core-component-repository[v1.8].
    - mehedi-iitdu/core-component-repository v1.8 requires php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - Root composer.json requires simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode ^4.2 -> satisfiable by simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode[4.2.0].
    - simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode 4.2.0 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
  Problem 7
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.0-RC1, ..., v8.0.3] require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.4, ..., v8.0.7] require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 || ~7.4.0 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.8, ..., v8.0.9] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.10, ..., v8.0.12] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.13, ..., v8.1.3] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
    - niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf[v4.0.0, ..., v4.1.0] require mpdf/mpdf ^8.0 -> satisfiable by mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.0-RC1, ..., v8.1.3].
    - Root composer.json requires niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf ^4.0 -> satisfiable by niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf[v4.0.0, v4.1.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Since I cloned this Laravel project from Github, I'm trying to set up my environment. When I run composer update or composer install it gives the above error.

I tried to using `composer update` or `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` but is still gives me the below error:

```
almando@think:~/Documents/laravelPro/active-ecommerce$ composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files
Class MercadoPago\RecuperableError located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Generic/RecuperableError.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\ErrorCause located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Generic/ErrorCause.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\SearchResultsArray located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Generic/SearchResultsArray.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Plan located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Plan.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\DiscountCampaign located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/DiscountCampaign.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\InstoreOrder located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/InstoreOrder.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\AuthorizedPayment located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/AuthorizedPayment.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\CardToken located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/CardToken.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Shipments located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shipments.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Refund located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Refund.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Preapproval located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Preapproval.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Payment located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Payment.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Track located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Track.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Item located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Item.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Documentation located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Documentation.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Payer located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Payer.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Tax located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Tax.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\TrackValues located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/TrackValues.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\PaymentMethod located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/PaymentMethod.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Subscription located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Subscription.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\AdvancedPayments\AdvancedPayment located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/AdvancedPayments/AdvancedPayment.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\AdvancedPayments\Refund located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/AdvancedPayments/Refund.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\AdvancedPayments\DisbursementRefund located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/AdvancedPayments/DisbursementRefund.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Card located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Card.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Invoice located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Invoice.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\POS located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/POS.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Preference located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Preference.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Chargeback located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Chargeback.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\OAuth located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/OAuth.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\MerchantOrder located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/MerchantOrder.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Customer located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Customer.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\MercadopagoSdkTest located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/tests/MercadoPagoSdkTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Payment located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Payment.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Track located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Track.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Item located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Item.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Documentation located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Documentation.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Payer located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Payer.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\Tax located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/Tax.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\TrackValues located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/TrackValues.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class MercadoPago\PaymentMethod located in ./vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entities/Shared/PaymentMethod.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Resources\V2\CategoryCollection located in ./app/Http/CategoryCollection.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: anandsiddharth/laravel-paytm-wallet
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: intervention/image
Discovered Package: kingflamez/laravelrave
Discovered Package: laracasts/flash
Discovered Package: laracon21/colorcodeconverter
Discovered Package: laracon21/combinations
Discovered Package: laracon21/timezones
Discovered Package: laravel/sanctum
Discovered Package: laravel/socialite
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravel/ui
Discovered Package: maatwebsite/excel
Discovered Package: mehedi-iitdu/core-component-repository
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: sebacarrasco93/laravel-payku
Discovered Package: simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-permission
Discovered Package: unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack
Package manifest generated successfully.
95 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Found 1 security vulnerability advisory affecting 1 package.
Run composer audit for a full list of advisories.
```

Comment: The reason(s) are outlined in the messages. What are you specifically concerned about? Which part of it is blocking your understanding?

Comment: And in the later part, those are diagnostic messages, not errors. They must not pose a restriction and your install did succeed. The earlier errors you're seeing (and they were blocking) because you're running composer with the php version 8.1. `--ignore-platform-req` handled it.

Comment: `requires php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.13) does not satisfy that requirement`  - anything unclear about that?

Comment: So what do i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your project was built on older PHP version (either 7.3 or 7.4, based on the dependencies) and you are using 8.1.
Besides, some of the dependencies, like `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` or `mpdf/mpdf` require [GD extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) which is missing in your system.

**First of all, you should not run `composer update` on a project you are unable to run as-is yet, because it might make things even worse.**

To get this one working, first install an older PHP version - I'd try 7.4 in this case and install all required extensions (GD in this case). Then run `composer install` again and see if that helped.

Second of all, you should pay more attention to the error messages provided by Composer as they already contain all these information and tips needed to solve the problem.
**Even though seeing 10 errors at once may seem a little overwhelming, follow each tip one by one to get rid of them.**

Comment: Thank you, you helped me out... is now working...! Thank you once more

Comment: You may consider approving the answer then @Hafenaaje